# FUSE (Bazil-Go): how to implement MkDir request?

Tags: go, mkdir, fuse

I am trying to implement the function `mkdir` in a fuse, written in Go,and I'm using [Bazil library](https://github.com/bazil/fuse/). I have successfully implemented a simple read-only fs, and I now want to be able to call `mkdir` inside any existing directory to make a new one.

I have made sure that all the existing directories are writable,(`attr.Mode = os.ModeDir | 0777`). 
Right now I have just added the function:

```
func (d Dir) MkDir(ctx context.Context, req *fuse.MkdirRequest) (fs.Node, error) {
    dir := &Dir{name: req.Name, files: 0, inode: 10 /*a random inode*/,mode: os.FileMode(0777),nextdir: nil, nextfile: nil}
    d.nextdir = dir
    return dir, nil
}
```

in my own implementation of the [hello fs example](https://github.com/bazil/fuse/blob/master/examples/hellofs/hello.go) of Bazil's library. But that doesn't seem to make any difference.

When I call `mkdir new_dir_name` from the terminal,  I get the error: "mkdir: cannot create directory ‘new_dir_name’: Operation not permitted", even though I have added the `mkdir` function.

Any insights as to why this is happening, and what else should I add to my code to make this working would be great. Also, this is my first stackoverflow question, so I'm sorry if I didn't ask in a clear way.

Comment: May be you have problem with access mode of parent dir, because you attache new dir to incoming `d.nextdir = dir` ?

Comment: I didn't show this: `d.nextdir`  is a pointer to a Dir struct type, like a linked list. 
And while assigning attributes(including Mode) to any Directory, I'm giving the os.filemode to be 0777

Answer (score 0):

the correct function for make directory like this

```
func (d *Dir) Mkdir(ctx context.Context, req *fuse.MkdirRequest) (fs.Node, error) {

}
```